Jetpack Compose: How to correctly force recompose when mutableStateOf object is changed from viewModel?
View:
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ActivityViewModel>()

Text("STATE: ${viewModel.state.activity?.invitation?.state?.title}")

ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class ActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ActivityRepository,
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) : ViewModel() {
    var state by mutableStateOf(ActivityScreenState())
        private set

    suspend fun fetchActivity(id: String) {
        val resource = repository.fetchActivity(id)
        val activity = resource.data

        resource.errorMessage?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        state = state.copy(
            isLoading = false,
            activity = activity,
        )
    }

    suspend fun accept(invitation: Invitation) {
        val tempActivity = state.activity
        tempActivity?.invitation?.state = InvitationState.ACCEPTED

        state = state.copy(
            activity = tempActivity,
        )
    }
}

ActivityScreenState:
data class ActivityScreenState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val activity: Activity? = null,
)

data class Activity(
    val id: String,
    val invitation: Invitation?,
)

data class Invitation(
    val id: String,
    var state: InvitationState,
)

enum class InvitationState(val title: String) {
    ACCEPTED("accepted"),
    DECLINED("declined"),
}

I have a viewModel, ActivityScreenState data class that contains Activity data class. When I update Activity inside the ActivityScreenState it doesn't recompose my composable view but I know it changes if I Log.d it.
I've tried searching but couldn't find what I'm doing wrong. Also found out it only recomposes if I nullify the activity inside ActivityScreenState.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

First of all, here you mean "recompose" by "recompile" so, correct the question. And are you assigning activity a non-null value at any point in the code?

@dev.tejasb thanks, updated the question. Yes I first fetch the activity from API and then try to update it after users presses a button. See the updated viewmodel code snippet.

can you try val state by remember { viewModel.state } Text("STATE: ${state.activity?.inspectionInvitation?.state?.title ?: "Unknown"}")

@dev.tejasb I'm getting highlighted error Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

replace by by =

@dev.tejasb thanks, that got rid of the error. But now it doesn't recompose the view  at all(even not when fetching the data for the first time).

can you try MutableStateFlow instead of mutableStateOf and use .collectAsState() in your composable?

Same issue, doesn't even work when fetching data for the first time.
var state = MutableStateFlow(InspectionActivityScreenState()) val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState() Text("STATE: ${state.value.activity?.inspectionInvitation?.state?.title ?: "Unknown"}")

when you use MutableStateFlow, you need to change state = state.copy(isLoading = false, activity = activity) to state.update {it.copy(isLoading = false,activity = activity)}

thanks, yeah, now it works for the first load, but doesn't recompose after state.activity is updated(the original issue).

I've noticed that it doesn't work only when activity is updated, if I update anything else inside ActivityScreenState, it works and view is recomposed. Maybe jetpack compose doesn't know how to recompose nested objects?

I took the liberty to update your code so that it compiles. Please verify that it is still what you want to ask and feel free to make any changes necessary.

The reason is data class uses equals and hashCode for structural equality == and with
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> structuralEqualityPolicy(): SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> =
    StructuralEqualityPolicy as SnapshotMutationPolicy<T>

private object StructuralEqualityPolicy : SnapshotMutationPolicy<Any?> {
    override fun equivalent(a: Any?, b: Any?) = a == b

    override fun toString() = "StructuralEqualityPolicy"
}

@StateFactoryMarker
fun <T> mutableStateOf(
    value: T,
    policy: SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> = structuralEqualityPolicy()
): MutableState<T> = createSnapshotMutableState(value, policy)

You are not updating parameters of ActivityScreenState
suspend fun accept(invitation: Invitation) {
    val tempActivity = state.activity
    tempActivity?.invitation?.state = InvitationState.ACCEPTED

    state = state.copy(
        activity = tempActivity
    )
}

you are not changing any properties of constructor of
data class ActivityScreenState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val activity: Activity? = null,
)

you are actually changing parameter of Activity while the instance remains same.
you should have new activity while you set same activity after changing state = InvitationState.ACCEPTED or you can use referentialEqualityPolicy() which triggers recomposition when new object is assigned.
suspend fun accept(invitation: Invitation) {
    val newActivity = state.activity.copy(activity = ...new instance here with copy or creating new Activity instance with new invitation)

    state = state.copy(
        activity = newActivity
    )
}

In general if you wish to force update with same value or different reference you can change snapshotMutationPolicies.
For instance

@Preview
@Composable
fun ForceRecpompositionSample() {
    Column {
        Composable1()
        Composable2()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Composable1() {
    var myCounter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MyCounter(0))
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, getRandomColor()).fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                myCounter = myCounter.copy(value = 5)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Update MyCounter")

        }
        Text("Value: ${myCounter.value}")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Composable2() {
    var myCounter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            value = MyCounter(0),
            policy = referentialEqualityPolicy()
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, getRandomColor()).fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                myCounter = myCounter.copy(value = 5)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Update MyCounter")

        }
        Text("Value: ${myCounter.value}")
    }
}

data class MyCounter(val value: Int)

if you check second composable you will see that you trigger recomposition even by setting same value of MyCounter while default one doesn't in Composable1.
getRandom color is a function that returns new color on recomposition to observer recomposition visually
fun getRandomColor() =  Color(
    red = Random.nextInt(256),
    green = Random.nextInt(256),
    blue = Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)

You can even force recomposition with Int or String values as well if change neverEquals policy such as
@Preview
@Composable
fun ForceRecompositionSample2() {
    var counter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            value = 0,
            policy = neverEqualPolicy()
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, getRandomColor()).fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                counter = 5
            }
        ) {
            Text("Update MyCounter")

        }
        Text("Value: ${counter}")
    }
}

If you wish to go with data class route you can update previous example as
data class MyCounter(
    val value: Int,
    val innerCounter: InnerCounter = InnerCounter()
)

data class InnerCounter(var value: Int = 0)

And to update InnerCounter and trigger recomposition check Composable2
@Composable
fun Composable1() {
    var myCounter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MyCounter(0))
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, getRandomColor()).fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                val innerCounter = myCounter.innerCounter
                val newValue = innerCounter.value + 1
                innerCounter.value = newValue
                myCounter = myCounter.copy()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Update MyCounter")

        }
        Text("Value: ${myCounter.value}")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Composable2() {
    var myCounter by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            value = MyCounter(0)
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, getRandomColor()).fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val innerCounter = myCounter.innerCounter
                val newValue = innerCounter.value + 1
                myCounter =
                    myCounter.copy(innerCounter = myCounter.innerCounter.copy(value = newValue))
            }
        ) {
            Text("Update MyCounter")

        }
        Text("Value: ${myCounter.value}")
    }
}


If you are dealing with data classes make sure that primary constructor params has changed with default policy. If you wish to trigger one time events you can move to class which doesn't come with equals and hashcode implementation or use different predefined or your custom SnapshotMutationPolicy

Thank you! referentialEqualityPolicy() did the trick! Didn't know that was a thing. Also thanks for the nice explanation.

You are welcome. Other one should work as well. Let me show with another example. If you change constructor params of data class as in second one you should be able to trigger recomposition

The other one works too. Thanks

Is there any disadvantage of using referentialEqualityPolicy? I mean except that it triggers even without changes to value(which shouldn't happen "accidentally")

no, there are no disadventages. I use them for one time events. override fun equivalent(a: Any?, b: Any?) = a === b is reference check. It depends on your implementation though. If you don't want to trigger recomposition any time you copy go with second route. You can check this tutorial for more references. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter4_state/Tutorial4_1_2SnapshotMutationPolicy.kt

These are basically saying when and with change of what you wish to trigger recomposition. neverEqual policy for instance returns false and because of that any value no matter what triggers recomposition. You can implement yours as well with some logic if you want to

This is great! Thanks a lot @Thracian
